# JS - Why don't I need return in nested then blocks

Tags: typescript, promise

I'm making some API calls that need to happen in sequence (one after the other, and the previous must be complete before the next one)

I just refactored some code to get rid of some bad looking nested then calls.

(simplified examples here - `any` is just for example, and I do actually use `responseOne`, `responseTwo` and `responseThree`)

So went from this:

```
axios.get('https://example.com', {})
  .then(function (responseOne: any) {
    axios.post('https://example.com', {}, {})
      .then(function (responseTwo: any) {
        axios.put('https://example.com', {}, {})
          .then(function (responseThree: any) {
            axios.post('https://example.com', {}, {})
              .then(function () {
                reply.send
              })
          })
      })
  })
```

to

```
axios.get('https://example.com', {})
  .then(function (responseOne: any) {
    return axios.post('https://example.com', {}, {})
  }).then(function (responseTwo: any) {
    return axios.put('https://example.com', {}, {})
  }).then(function (responseThree: any) {
    return axios.post('https://example.com', {}, {})
  }).then(function () {
    reply.send
  })
```

The bit I don't understand is why I had to add returns in the second approach, but not the nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the second approach *chains* the calls to `.then()`, so each one needs to return a `Promise` to keep that chain going.

In the original code no such chaining was taking place, and each nested operation was simply waiting for its own `Promise` to finish before invoking the next operation.  It didn't matter for any given operation if the next one was also going to be a `Promise` or even if the previous one was a `Promise`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `then` on the promise you want to wait to settle.

In each case, that promise is the return value of `axios.post()`.

In your first example, you access that return value *directly*.

In your second example, you have to return the promise so that it will be adopted by the next `then` in sequence. If you didn't do that, this would happen:

```
make_first_promise().then(() => {
    make_second_promise();
}).then(() => {
    // The previous `then` resolves with `undefined` **before** the second promise has resolved
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following three scenarios:

1. Each `then` method call returns a promise. If the callback function passed to the `then` method returns nothing, the promise of the `then` method is fulfilled with the value of `undefined`.

   If the callback function contains some asynchronous operation, then the promise returned by the `then` method **won't wait** for the asynchronous operation to complete. The code inside the callback will get executed and the promise returned by the `then` method will fulfil with the `undefined` value as soon as its callback execution ends.
2. If the callback function returns a non-promise value, the promise returned by the `then` method fulfils with that value.
3. If the callback functions returns a promise, then the promise of the `then` method is *resolved* to the promise returned by the callback function. In simple words, this means that the outer `then` method promise (let's call it `p1`) now depends on the inner callback function promise (let's call it `p2`). If `p2` fulfils, `p1` also fulfils with the same value. If `p2` is rejected, `p1` also gets rejected with the same rejection value.

   In other words, `p1` will wait for `p2` to settle and `p1` won't settle until `p2` settles. This is generally what we want when the callback of the `then` method contains an asynchronous operation.

In your case, if you don't return the result of `axios.post(...)`, then the first scenario applies. In this case, the callback function of the next `then` method call will be passed `undefined` as a parameter. However, in your case, this is not important. What's important is that the `then` method promise **won't wait for the inner promise (returned by the callback function) to settle**. This is not what you want.

What you want is for each `then` method to wait for the HTTP request in its callback function to complete before next `then` method's callback is invoked. To achieve this, you need to return the result of `axios.post(...)` so that your code falls under the 3rd scenario mentioned above.